# Повторное выполнение функции при нажатии

Tags: jquery, javascript, функции

Есть функция

```
  this.showWarning = function(warning){
        $(self.mysignWindow).stop(true,false).animate({height:370},300);
        $('h1').stop(true,false).stop(true,false).animate({bottom:430},300);
        $(".line2").before("<p class='warning'>"+warning+"</p>");
        var time = setTimeout(function(){
            $(self.mysignWindow).stop(true,false).animate({height:320},300);
            $('h1').stop(true,false).animate({bottom:370},300);
            $(".warning").remove();            
            console.log("ddfs");
        },3000);

    }
```

когда я много раз кликаю на button она вызывается много раз 
как сделать так , чтобы она не вызывалась пока предыдущая не закончила свою роботу?

Comment: когда считается рОбота законченной ? поставьте флажок принадлежащий  внешней области видимости. кстати `var time` у вас бесполезен абсолютно.

Comment: знаю,я просто тогда пробовал и не стер

Answer (score 6):

Используй локальный мьютекс http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion

```
this.showWarning = function(warning){
    // выполняется ли код?
    if (self.showWarningMutex||false) return; // это конструкция на случай когда self.showWarningMutex ещё не известен (undefined)

    // не выполняется - занять
    self.showWarningMutex = true;

    ..

    // выполнилось - освободить
    self.showWarningMutex = false;
}
```

Comment: в асинхронной функции this будет другим. (hint  - у него там self есть)

Comment: `this.showWarningMutex||false`

То ли я сломался, то ли false здесь вообще не меняет картину никак.

Comment: исправил код, добавил комментарий

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev, undefined же сам скастуется в false, нет? (из-за этого управляющая конструкция и перейдет ко второму условие "или")

с т.з. выполнения кода это конечно некритично все